# What's the label for in `ModelForm`

Tags: django

I am building a web following the instruction.
I didn't understand the labels attributes:

```
class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text':''}
```

The Topic in `models.py` does not specify labels attributes:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

What's the labels for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The label argument lets you specify the “human-friendly” label for a specific field. Generally used in a Form.

The default label for a Field is generated from the **field name** by converting all underscores to spaces and upper-casing the first letter

```
the_name = forms.CharField()
```

Label is: **The name**

```
name = forms.CharField(label='Your name')
```

Label is: **Your name** because we set the label argument

Source : [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#label)